# Does accidental vinegar have a culture that I can pass along?

Tags: food-science, vinegar, starter

**Background:** A couple of years ago we left a half drunk bottle of Sirah on the counter and it went to vinegar. A really nice vinegar with a pleasant, mild flavor, and we've been using splash here and a bit there ever since. Now I'm down to circa half a cup.

Is this a live culture like a bread starter? Can I buy a bottle of a similar wine, and intentionally propagate the flavor of this stuff? Or is just a crap-shoot?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_vinegar ... but I have no idea about the flavor.

Comment: 'What's so unpleasant about being drunk?' 'You ask a glass of water.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This video of Alton Brown - Good Eats explains it way better than I ever can.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JEi4OW2Q54

If your bottle of wine turned to vinegar you probably have some "mother" at the bottom of that bottle that you can use in your next batch.

Comment: I don't seem to have big wad of mother, but I do have loose floating bits of something. Possibly I'm good to go.

Comment: Since you have loose stuff try straining it, you might have more than you think.